# CentOS7: configure static ip and ifconfig: command not found

Tags: ip, centos7

All I am trying to do is assign a static IP to a server. As per instructions online, I made following changes in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=xxxx (a valid name)
UUID=0c1c2330-b5aa-4fac-952e-ac61153853a7
DEVICE=(valid name)
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.1.xx (valid IP)
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

After this I ran :

`service network restart`

After which I try running `ifconfig` and I get:

`bash: ifconfig: command not found`

I cant ping google.com or install any packages using yum, for example when I try to run `yum provides ifconfig` , I get the following :

Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?          release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"`

One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail.

This made me think that I need to add nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf file, so I added this to that file:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and then I again restarted network service and tried to ping google.com and ended up getting:

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

I would appreciate any help that I can get in solving this. Thank you.

Comment: What does your network administrator say?

Comment: I have to figure it out. No network administrator here. Does it have something to with PATH or providing gateway?

Comment: So who allocated you that static IP address, and why didn't they tell you what your default gateway should be?

Comment: I am going by the current addresses being used on other servers and the static IP that I am using in the current server is the next one.

Comment: Why has my question been downvoted?

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Comment: I think it is pretty useful. I did do the research and is going by what online articles say. If it is too much trouble or someone cant answer the question, that is not my fault. Feel free to delete the question or however it can be closed. I will figure it out myself.

Comment: `ifconfig` was deprecated long ago, and isn't shipped with modern Linux distributions by default. Use `ip` instead, e.g. `ip address` (`ip a`) or `ip route` (`ip r`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145447/ifconfig-command-not-found

now, short story:

```
nmtui
systemctl restart NetworkManager (maybe)
```

long one:

Reading good documentation is the solution: you can find some
information [there](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/part-IP_Networking.html). Inside that book you have [nmtui](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Networking_Config_Using_nmtui.html).